# wp_insert_user not working on cron job

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to do a wordpress cron job, and the wp_insert_user function is not working

```
$user_data = array(
'user_login'        => $fields['employee_number'],
'user_pass'         => wp_hash_password($fields['employee_number']),
'user_nicename'     => $fields['employee_number'],
'user_email'        => $fields['email_address'],
'user_registered'   => $fields['modify_datetime'],
'display_name'      => $fields['family_name'] . ' ' . $fields['given_name']
);

$user_ID = wp_insert_user($user_data);
```

Is there any solution that anyone is familiar with? Or do i need to require once some file?

using below to call it:

`add_action('update_users_when_time_comes', array($this, 'update_users_when_time_comes'));`

When i call my function on cron its not working, but if i call it on

`add_action('admin_head', array($this, 'update_users_when_time_comes'));`

its working

Comment: Please check this kink "https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user"

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs im not getting any error, the code under the function is not executed

Comment: @Scenox then how are you running it? either there is an error (check your error logs and use `ini_set` to display errors) or the code isn't being run

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs 
add_action('update_users_when_time_comes', array($this, 'update_users_when_time_comes'));
When i call my function on cron its not working, but if i call it on 
add_action('admin_head', array($this, 'update_users_when_time_comes'));
its working

Comment: @Scenox added this as edit suggestion - please rm comment if approved :)

Answer (score 0):

You must have to include this file to use wp_insert_user function:

```
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php' );
```